# IdentityServer and Microservices: Missing Sub Claims

Tags: microservices, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

I am having this error after logging from the identity server.

> InvalidOperationException: sub claim is missing
>   IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerAuthenticationService.AssertRequiredClaims(ClaimsPrincipal principal) in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Hosting\IdentityServerAuthenticationService.cs, line 119

I am using implicit grant types for my web api running with swagger ui. Everything seems fine when I typed in Client Id and Scope in the popup. It redirect me to Identity Server login screen. Once typed in the login details, this error shown.

I think my configured in my web api and identity server should be fine. I am thinking may be some claim missing in my identity server database.

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "parent.api.gateway",
                ClientName = "Parent Api Gateway",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5100/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5100/swagger/" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    "api1"
                }
            },
```

The above code is a inMemory of my setting, I put it inside the database.

Comment: Did you try adding openid and profile scope?

Comment: I realized I need to add sub and name in the aspidentityClaim table